# Wrong like count from Facebook fql.query

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

any idea why it displays 2 likes here:

http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://rodenstock.fbapp.eu/gallery/image/508&layout=box_count

and 0 here:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20like_count,%20total_count,%20url,%20share_count,%20click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22https://rodenstock.fbapp.eu/gallery/image/508%22

and 0 here:

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=https://rodenstock.fbapp.eu/gallery/image/508

I know that the number next to the like-button counts shares and likes together. But this does not explain the numbers.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers are now ok.
I guess it was either a temporary error or the cache for (new url-?) querys can take up to ~20h to refresh.

Comment: there is also a related bugreport:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/169035286562837?browse=search_4ff42ceea5e242238926600